# Не работает код (PHP)

Tags: php

Не могу найти ошибку в коде. Нужна помощь.

```
$aCities = array(
    "Московская область" => array("Москва", "Зеленоград", "Клин"),
    "Ленинградская область" => array("Санкт-Петербург", "Всеволожск", "Павловск", "Кронштадт"),
    "Рязанская область" => array("Рязань", "Касимов", "Ряжск")
);

foreach ($aCities as $sKey => $aCity) {    

    echo("$sKey:" . "\n\r");      
        foreach ($aCity as $sCity) {         
            mb_substr($sCity, 0, 1) != 'К' ?: print "$sCity<br>";   
    }
    echo "\n\r";
}
```

Comment: код рабочый, ошибок в нем нету, ищите причину не в нем

Comment: что выдает у вас в логах?

Comment: Я юзаю https://ideone.com. Изза среды значит ругается?

Comment: а какая ошибка у вас показывается?

Comment: Код работает http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/109dea6deb7b3f2510898ec028c2212440676038

Comment: В функции `mb_substr`  укажите четвертый параметр - кодировку `UTF-8`

Comment: Ошибка выполнения #stdin #stdout #stderr 0.02s 23436KB
Вот эту штуку выдает

Comment: это не трабл. Это для unicode приставка, просто на этом сервере mb_substr отключена

Comment: да, читайте ниже - PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_substr() in /home/OHamD3/prog.php:14

Comment: Установите расширение php-mbstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

с кодировкой мб трабл - mb_substr - замените на substr

Comment: нет, это не трабл. Это для unicode приставка, просто на этом сервере она откоючена